# Amazon SQS getMessageID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Amazon SQS delivers only at least one delivery. So i have to proof whether the Message is send a second time. Is it possible to identify the delete of a unique Message with the getMessageID() method? That I can store the String in a data structure and match it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [receive an SQS message](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html), there are two relevant items sent along with the [message](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_Message.html):

> **MessageId**
>
> A unique identifier for the message. Message IDs are considered unique across all AWS accounts for an extended period of time.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: No
>
> **ReceiptHandle**
>
> An identifier associated with the act of receiving the message. A new receipt handle is returned every time you receive a message. When deleting a message, you provide the last received receipt handle to delete the message.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: No

So to identify duplicate messages, you would need to:

- store the MessageIds that you have received
- check if a new message's MessageId already exists in your MessageId store

You could also store ReceiptHandles, but if you care about only receiving them once then I think that storing MessageIds would be sufficient to imply that it had already been received once.

Once you identify a duplicate, you can use the duplicate message's ReceiptHandle to [delete the duplicate message](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessage.html), if you wish.

Comment: How does this tell the difference between a true duplicate versus a failed message that is being retried? In both cases, the messageId will look the same.

Comment: @aaa90210 With respect, this doesn't answer your case because it is quite a bit more nuanced than what the original poster asked. Could you [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with these specific details instead?